# Pilha em python

Tags: python, stack

não estou conseguindo resolver um exercicio utilizando pilha em python...

Uma sequencia de parenteses "(" ")", colchetes "[" "]" e chaves "{" "}" 
é dita balanceada se cada simbolo "aberto" é "fechado" 
em um momento apropriado.
Preciso escrever uma funcao "balanceada" que recebe uma string e
retorna "True" se a string representa uma sequencia balanceada, 
"False" caso contrário.

A função só vai receber parênteses, colchetes e
chaves.

pensei assim....mas não está dando certo...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tatiane, procure colocar o código e não a imagem do mesmo, por favor, fica mais fácil pra galera analisar e te responder.

Answer (score 2):

Tatiane, seu primeiro if vendo o valor de i está incorreto, e sua verificação no segundo if, é necessária que seja isolada com parênteses, veja uma possível correção:

```
def balanceada(string):
  pilha = []
  for i in string:
    #Aqui as condições de igualdade estavam erradas
    #if i =='(' or '[' or '{':
    if i =='(' or i =='[' or i == '{':
      pilha.append(i)
    else:
      topo = pilha[-1]
      #Cuidado ao utilizar OR, normalmente temos que isolar com parênteses
      #if i == ")" and topo == "(" or i == "]" and topo == "[" or i == "}" and topo == "{"
      if ( i == ")" and topo == "(" ) or ( i == "]" and topo == "[" ) or ( i == "}" and topo == "{" ):
        pilha.pop()
      else:
        return False
  if len(pilha) == 0:
    return True
  else:
    return False

print( balanceada("()[]{}") )
print( balanceada("{[})") )
```